# Is there another way to reverse last and first name in a string

Tags: c#, string

It will reverse last and first name in a string. Is there another more efficient way? I have a need for high performing code that uses LINQ.

example input) JOHNSON JEN
example input) JOHNSON JOSHUA CHUCK (last,first,middle)
example input) JOHNSON, JODY

```
appAm.AccountName.Replace(", ",",").Replace(" ",",").Substring(appAm.AccountName.Replace(", ", ",").Replace(" ", ",").IndexOf(",") + 1).Trim()) + " " + (appAm.AccountName.Replace(", ", ",").Replace(" ", ",").Substring(0, appAm.AccountName.Replace(", ", ",").Replace(" ", ",").IndexOf(",")).Trim())
```

Comment: For a start, maybe use some local variables so that you're not repeating the same replacements four times.

Comment: What if they have more than one space in their name, like "Bob Alex Smith"?  How do you know if the "Alex" is a middle name, or part of the last name?...

Comment: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)  And how about you store the data properly: different columns for first, middle and last names, then the whole problem falls away

Comment: What are all the `Replace` commands for? It would be helpful to see sample input and expected output. There are many ways to manipulate strings, but we'd need to know what we're working with.

Comment: Why do you call `Trim` on a string where you replaced all the spaces with commas? Are there other whitespace characters in the input string? Also it would be more efficient to create a new string with the spaces removed or replaced with commas than to call `Replace` so many times on the same string.

Comment: This will swap the first and last entries, but leave everything in the middle alone: `            var values = appAm.AccountName.Split(", ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            var first = values.FirstOrDefault();
            var last = values.LastOrDefault();
            values[0] = last;
            values[values.Length - 1] = first;
            appAm.AccountName = String.Join(", ", values);`

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to manipulate strings. It would be helpful if we could see sample input and expected output, but I believe this code produces similar results to yours:

```
// Create an array of the names (by splitting on commas and spaces)
var nameParts = appAm.AccountName.Split(new [] {',', ' '}, 
    StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

// Reverse the order of the names
Array.Reverse(nameParts);

// Join the names again with a space
appAm.AccountName = string.Join(" ", nameParts);
```

Also, your code would be more efficient if you only did the replacements and comma lookup once:

```
appAm.AccountName = appAm.AccountName.Replace(", ", ",").Replace(" ",",");
int commaPosition = appAm.AccountName.IndexOf(",")

appAm.AccountName = appAm.AccountName.Substring(commaPosition + 1) + " " + 
    appAm.AccountName.Substring(0, commaPosition)
```

Note that this is not really a good approach, depending on what you need. Parsing names can be very difficult. For example, try this with `"Robert Downey Jr."`, or `"King Edward VII"`, whose name is `"Edward Albert Christian George Andrew Patrick David"`.